# TypeError: Cannot read property 'password' of undefined while using MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, routes

Was trying to login via routes authentication, it is not verifying the user (with encrypted password) from the database when the user is registered already.

Code snippet:

```
exports.patientLogin= async (req,res)=>{
try {
    const {email,password}=req.body;
    if(!email || !password)
    {
        return res.status(400).render('login',{
            message:'Provide email and password'
        })
    }

    db.query('Select * FROM patient WHERE email= ?',[email],(error,results)=>{
        console.log(results);
        if(!results || !(bcrypt.compare(password,results[0].password))){
        res.status(401).render('patientLogin',{
            message:'Email or password is incorrect!'
        })
    }
  


    else{
        const id =results[0].id;
        const token=jwt.sign({ id },process.env.JWT_SECRET,{
            expiresIn: process.env.JWT_EXPIRES_IN
        });
        console.log("Token is: " + token);

        const cookieOptions={
            expires:new Date(
                Date.now() + process.env.JWT_COOKIE_EXPIRES * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
            ),
            httpOnly: true
        }
        res.cookie('jwt',token,cookieOptions);
        res.status(200).redirect("/");
    }
    })

} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);    }
```

}

below is the error occurring while submitting login and password in the login-form

```
D:\Node\Easy-Cure\EasyCure-Main\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:437
  throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
  ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'password' of undefined
at Query.<anonymous> (D:\Node\Easy-Cure\EasyCure-Main\controllers\auth.js:25:65)
at Query.<anonymous> (D:\Node\Easy-Cure\EasyCure-Main\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:526:10)
at Query._callback (D:\Node\Easy-Cure\EasyCure-Main\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:488:16)
at Query.Sequence.end (D:\Node\Easy-Cure\EasyCure-Main\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:83:24)
at Query._handleFinalResultPacket (D:\Node\Easy-Cure\EasyCure-Main\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:149:8)
at Query.EofPacket (D:\Node\Easy-Cure\EasyCure-Main\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:133:8)
at Protocol._parsePacket (D:\Node\Easy-Cure\EasyCure-Main\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:291:23)
at Parser._parsePacket (D:\Node\Easy-Cure\EasyCure-Main\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:433:10)
at Parser.write (D:\Node\Easy-Cure\EasyCure-Main\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:43:10)
at Protocol.write (D:\Node\Easy-Cure\EasyCure-Main\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:38:16)
```

Comment: What does `console.log(results)` show? Looks like the query just returned an empty array. 

Also you are using `bcrypt.compore` incorrectly, it will return a promise so you should `await` the result of the promise to get the boolean otherwise you will always get `true` because Promise is an object and an object is casted to `true`.

Comment: not getting any result at console, please help.

Comment: Looks like you are doing a request where a user with such `email` does not exist. Please run the query manually and see what you get in `MySQL Workbench` you need to check whether there is data that matches your query. Also, add a logic to handle a situation when a user with provided email does not exist.